# Working with multiple factories in angular

Tags: angularjs

I was working with only 1 factory in angular, but now that my project has grown too large, I want to split the file in separate factories.

My factories are like this:

```
angular.module('factories')
.factory('auth', ['$http', '$state', '$window',
    function($http, $state, $window) {
        var auth = {};

        ......

        return auth;
```

Userfactory:

```
angular.module('factories')
.factory('userFactory', ['$http', '$state', '$window',
  function($http, $state, $window) {
    var userFactory = {};
    return userFactory;
```

I inject them in my controllers:

```
angular.module('controllers')
.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'auth', 'userFactory', 'Facebook',
    function ($scope, $state, auth, userFactory, Facebook) {
```

However I get the following error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=userFactoryProvider%20%3C-%20userFactory%20%3C-%20UserCtrl

I'm also bootstrapping my factories:

```
angular.module('factories', []);
```

And I inject factories into app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('eva', ['ui.router', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages',
  'controllers', 'factories', 'ngAnimate', '720kb.socialshare',
  'angular-loading-bar', 'angular-svg-round-progress', 'pascalprecht.translate',
  'facebook']);
```

What is the proper way to work with multiple factories?

Comment: Angular simply cant find your "userFactory" factory. Can you add this specific factory declaration code ?

Comment: `And I inject factories into app.js` can you show us what you mean by this?

Comment: Edited the OP once again.

Comment: Where does `userFactoryProvider` fit into all this? It seems that's what the errors actually referring to so might be a good place to start

Comment: You don't need to inject your factories into your module declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you imported the script into your index file. You need files from both of services to be imported after the angular.js file.

Answer (score 2):

Since factories are in a separate module so you need to set dependency for `controller` module because it is using factories from `factories` module.

Do something like

```
angular.module('controllers', ['factories'])
.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'auth', 'userFactory', 'Facebook',
function ($scope, $state, auth, userFactory, Facebook) {
```